# Getting raster extent excluding nodata area

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have a GeoTiff raster in which half of its area is nodata. The problem is that the raster extent includes the nodata area.

Is there a way with GDal to recalculate the extent of the raster excluding the nodata areas?

With help from @user30184 here is how to get the raster extent of an image without nodata border.

1. Replace all nodata pixels with 0 and all other pixels with 1

   gdal_calc.py -A source_image.tif --outfile out.tif --NoDataValue 0 --calc="1*(A>0)"
2. Get the shape file for the meaningful area.

   gdal_polygonize.py -8 -b 1 -f "ESRI Shapefile" out.tif pols
3. Clip the source_image.tif with the shape file to create a new tif with updated extent.

gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline pols/out.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha 3559007_2014-05-08_RE5_3A_181809processed.tif OUTPUT.tif

[image: Source Image]

Comment: I do not know any direct way for that but if you have only a few images you could perhaps have a try by vectorizing them with gdal_polygonize.py and deleting the no-data polygons from the resulting vector layer.

Comment: It is too slow, my file is 240MB and after the polygonization the result shp files becomes bigger then 500MB.

Comment: How about opening image into QGIS and digitizing extents manually as a polygon? Or before running gdal_polygonize.py use gdal_calc.py and convert image to 1-bit image: nodata pixels=0 and other pixels=1.

Comment: Replacing all meaningful pixels and all nodata pixels with 1 and 0 works perfect!

But my new problem is how to recalculate the extent for the result shape file according to the old extent.

Comment: this is essentially the same question as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45159/finding-minimum-bounding-extent-of-given-pixel-value-within-raster/. The embedded answer should be extracted and placed as an answer and fetch it's due up-votes. (tip: to speed up processing time and reduce redundant disk storage, use a "virtual raster table" ([tag:VRT]) for intermediate steps).