# Is there a "trim" function in Gdal which would remove a NODATA border

Tags: raster, gdal

There is a function in R ([trim](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.5-8/topics/trim)) which removes the NODATA situated in the outer rim of a raster (entire external row or column made of nodata).  It is realy simple but quite slow.  I am looking for a similar function or algorithm in gdal to do that.  Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like the equivalent of GIMP's "zealous crop"

This is doable with the **-cutline** option in **gdal_translate**, but then you need to create the vector representing the valid raster data extent yourself.

Postgres has the [ST_MinConvexHull](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_MinConvexHull.html), taking the ST_Envelope of that would be equivalent to what you described. Sounds a bit like overkill, though.

An easier way is with SAGA's [crop to data](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.3.0/grid_tools_17.html) raster method, which is available via processing. That does both steps in one (and can also do multiple rasters in one go)

Comment: I like the SAGA way, I'll use that as it seems easier then finding the extent of my valid raster to put into -cutline.  Thanks

Comment: Here's a gdal script that will trim so long as entire image can fit in memory - https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/149511/108