# Finding xy coordinates of high and low elevation values in DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, elevation, arcgis-10.4, hazus

I have a 32-bit floating point GRID containing elevation data created in Hazus 3.2. The area defines the elevation of a specific boundary for a flood study. I need to find the xy data for the high and low elevations within the DEM. I basically need to do the opposite of the [Get Cell Value tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-cell-value.htm)

I can't figure out a good way to do it. I do have the Spatial Analyst extension at my disposal as well.

Comment: Maybe you can convert your raster to a point dataset, and then find a way to select the points with the lowest and highest value. I would use the sort function on the elevation field and select the first and the last feature.

Comment: Select the extreme points and intersect them with both coordinate grids.  Coordinate grid creation is discussed at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13445.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to calculate the statistics of the raster, which will give you the minimum and maximum cell values (check the raster properties).  Then you can use the Spatial Analyst Con tool to pick out those cells and determine the high/low locations.